# Prevent re-rendering when state is changed multiple times during useEffect

Tags: reactjs

In my React app, I will implement useState multiple times in a single component. Then in my useEffect I will change the state of several of these:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const Projects = React.memo(function (props) {

    const [someState1, setSomeState1] = useState(false);
    const [someState2, setSomeState2] = useState(false);
    const [someState3, setSomeState3] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
         if (someConditionMet) {
             setSomeState1(true);
             setSomeState2(true);
             setSomeState3(true);
         }
    });

    if (initialized) {
        return <div>Hello World</div>;
});
```

What I notice is that each time setSomeState1, setSomeState2, setSomeState3 is called, the entire component gets re-rendered for each of these calls. I really only want it to re-render once when useEffect has completed. Is there a way in React to prevent the rendering from happening multiple times when multiple states are changed within useEffect?

Comment: Does using a dependency array on the effect hook make any difference?

Comment: @DrewReese I tried adding [someState1, someState2, someState3]  but this didn't help.

Comment: Well, I didn't specify *how* the dependency array is populated. As written your effect would trigger on every render no matter what. Assuming you're familiar with class-based components: an empty dependency array is synonymous to `componentDidMount`, while a populated array is synonymous to `componentDidUpdate`. You may also find [eslint-plugin-react-hooks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-hooks) helpful in your project.

Comment: The `setSomeStateX` setters are stable references in functional components so I wouldn't expect them to trigger the effect. It appears as though your effect is dependent upon `someConditionMet` in order to update state. All state updates queued during *a render* cycle work the same in functional components as they do in class-based components.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to add a dependency array to your useEffect so that the condition will be called only once

```
useEffect(() => {
     if (someConditionMet) {
         setSomeState1(true);
         setSomeState2(true);
         setSomeState3(true);
     }
},[]);
```

Comment: Totally forgot about that. I'm new to React. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I tried out your suggestion but the rendering still happens every time setSomeStateX is called. Instead of [ ] I used [someState1, someState2, someState3]

Answer (score 0):

Try useRef instead useState , that won't cause rendering multiple times.